# One site will not load on TOR

Tags: configuration, windows, onion-routing

I have used TOR for a while now, and I have no problems, except it is a bit slow to load pages, which is fine.

[www.netspend.com/activation](http://www.netspend.com/activation)  is a site to activate a VISA debit card, which I want to activate anonymously. It won't load.

On any other browser it comes up in a second or two. I've tried TOR on two workstations, windows 7 and windows 10.

I've seen references to TOR not being 'set up' correctly; do I need to configure this somehow? Are some sites more sensitive to onion browsing and all this relaying than others?

I'm starting to think this site will not load to a browser that appears to be not in the US, since the card is only valid there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does load just fine from EU.
They will just block tor traffic, because, like, who activates his cc via tor won't do good, they think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like they're using a Cloudflare or a similar service to do tor blocking and CDN service. They **do** track you as you're using their service, so - discard them, there's nothing more you can do from your side